# How to find the analytic formula of this second-order ODE?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

What is the best way to solve this ODE and get the analytic formula for:

$$
f’’[y] + (1/2) f’[y]^2 - (3/2) ~y ~ Exp[-2f[y]] =0
$$

I tried :

`ic:= {F[0]==0, f’[0]==0}`

`DSolve[{Eq,ic},f,y]`

But `DSolve` doesn’t give a solution whether by initial conditions or not.

I tried `NDSolve` then to use fitting after that

`sol=NDSolveValue[{eq==0,ic},f,{y,0,4}]`

`tab=Tabel[{y,sol[y]},{y,Range[tmin,4,0.01]}];`

In trying to find the appropriate fitting function for this numerical solution I used:

`f1= NonlinearModelFit[tab,Log[a+by],{a,b},y]`

`f2= NonlinearModelFit[tab, a Exp[y b],{a,b},y]`

`f3= NonlinearModelFit[tab, a+b y^2,{a,b},y]`

But neither of these functions fits the solution. So how to find the exact fitting function?  I don't want to use `FindFormula` cause it gives along series in y, and I expect the `f[y]` formula to be simple like the fitting functions I tried.

Or is there a way to find an analytic solution directly?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Most DE do not have an analytic solution. Therefore it is quit possible, because MMA is not able to find an analytic solution, that non exists. Further, note that the initial conditions f[0]==0 and f'[0]==0 contradict the DE.

Comment: So how to find the correct fitting function? I think MA can fit any numeric solution or plot.

Comment: How do you know that `f[0] =0 ` and `f’[0]=0`contradict the equation?

Comment: Sorry, it is wrong, I overlooked the y in 3/2 y Exp[-2 f[x]]

Comment: Why not posting all equations in Mathematica form? It is really annoying to retype the equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find an approximate analytical function that approximates a numerical solution, you may proceed as:

First get a numerical solution;

```
eq = {f''[x] + 1/2 f'[x]^2 - 3/2 Exp[-2 f[x]] == 0, f[0] == 0, f'[0] == 0};
sol = f /. NDSolve[eq, f, {x, 0, 4}][[1]]
Plot[sol[x], {x, 0, 4}]
```

[image]

Then choose some orthogonal function system, e.g. polynomials, or circular functions or... For an example, I choose simple polynomials:

```
fit = LinearModelFit[
  Table[{x, sol[x]}, {x, 0, 4, 0.1}], {1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5}, x]
```

[image]

Now we plot the difference between the approximation and the numerical function:

[image]

Comment: I don't want to use a Polyniomal function or a series in y, so that I didn't use `FindFormula`. I hope to find a simpler formula

Comment: If there is no analytic solution, the chance that you find a much simpler function is small. For my example, you could try: p1 ArcTan[y-p2]+Pi with parameters p1 and p2

Comment: Yeah, I realized that it will be a Polynomial function. Thank you!

Comment: I am a bit confused, I tried Bob Halon's solution and I get an analytic solution . Maybe there was no problem after all?

Comment: You have a typo in your equation;  it should be `f''[x] + 1/2 f'[x]^2 - 3/2 x Exp[-2 f[x]] == 0` (note the  `x` in front of the `Exp` factor.)  I think that Bob Hanlon copied your equation, with the typo, and it happened that the equation with the typo was soluble.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Interesting how chance sometimes plays a bad joke on us.

Answer (score 4):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (June 3, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

eq = {f''[x] + 1/2 f'[x]^2 - 3/2 Exp[-2 f[x]] == 0, f[0] == 0, f'[0] == 0};

sol = DSolve[eq, f, x]

(* Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.

Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.

{{f -> Function[{x}, Log[1/12 (12 + 9 x^2)]]}} *)
```

Verifying the solution,

```
eq /. sol[[1]] // Simplify

(* {True, True, True} *)
```

Therefor,

```
f[x_] = f[x] /. sol[[1]]

(* Log[1/12 (12 + 9 x^2)] *)

Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 4}]
```

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't the equation be `f''[x] + 1/2 f'[x]^2 - 3/2 x Exp[-2 f[x]] == 0`?  (Note the  `x` in front of the `Exp` factor)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert - I just copied the equation from the accepted answer since the OP did not post their code.

Comment: Yeah, after I posted this comment I noticed that it was incorrect there too.